# overlapping text on a fig

Tags: ieeetran

I am trying to write a IEEE paper [image]. i would like to center the image and the text in the second column should come below the fig.

thank you

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You should add the code for this particular section (along with the necessary packages), otherwise it's impossible for us to do anything.

Comment: Relevant perhaps: http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-widefigs.html

Comment: Use `\begin{figure*}...\end{figure*}` for getting a double column figure.

Comment: Beside use `figure*`, inside this environment use `\centering`. BTW,  generally is a good practice set the width of the image to  `\linewidth` or a  some fraction of it (e.g. `0.7\linewidth`). This way the image never will be wider that the float.

Comment: \begin{figure}[h]
\centering
 \includegraphics[width=15cm, height=8cm]{F(u)_bl300.png}
%\includegraphics[scale=1.75]{step1.png}
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\caption{Left: Full force displacement curve. \\ Right: Only unloading with linear approximation.}
 \label{fig:step1}
\end{figure}

\subsection{Nano Indentation}
For .....

Comment: That was the code which i used and also i tried it in \begin{figure*}...\end{figure*} but this time the fig was not at all called

Comment: \documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}


Used these packages

Comment: \begin{strip}
\centering
 \includegraphics[width=15cm, height=8cm]{F(u)_bl300.png}
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\captionof{figure}{Left: Full force displacement curve. \\ Right: Only unloading with linear approximation.}
 \label{fig:F(u) curve}
\end{strip}


my prob is solved using strip environment